# BigDecimal comparsion in Apache Velocity

Tags: velocity

I have a checkbox that should be checked if some `BigDecimal` value is greater that zero. I tried this:

```
<input title="$i18n.tr('foo')" type="checkbox" name="foo.bar" id="foobar"
#if($foo.bar && $foo.bar.doubleValue() > 0)checked#end/>
```

(`foo` is a POJO and `bar` is `BigDecimal` field)

But no matter what stores in `bar`, checkbox is always unchecked. I tried to add `onclick` event in order to debug it:

```
onclick="alert('$foo.bar.doubleValue()');"
```

And here I can see that bar's value is OK, e.g. `15.0`, so it's not a value's problem.

How to compare `BigDecimal` with another number in Velocity's template?

Comment: This **should** work. Did you check that the problem isn't someplace else? For example, is the attribute present in the HTML source, but the state was wrongly cached by the browser? Is the way the HTML is processed dropping the attribute since it's not valid XML? Debug in other ways: print `$foo.bar.class`, print something else outside the input element in a similar `#if`, do two other `#if`s with only one part of the the condition, etc. By the way, which version of Velocity are you using?

Comment: @SergiuDumitriu `$foo.bar.class` is `class java.math.BigDecimal`. Also, there's no `checked` in HTML after render. One part of condition doesn't work too. Velocity version: 1.4

Comment: And upgrading to a newer version of Velocity is not possible, right?

Comment: What about `$foo.bar.doubleValue().compareTo(0.0) > 0`?

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered ".0)\')\"/>\r\n Was expecting one of:
"," ...
")" ...
...`

Comment: And without `.0`: `java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'compareTo' in class java.lang.Double threw exception class java.lang.ClassCastException : java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`

Comment: And no updates, sorry =)

Comment: Velocity 1.4 doesn't really support non-integer numbers... What about: `#set ($zero = 0) #if ($foo.bar && $foo.bar.doubleValue().compareTo($zero.doubleValue()) > 0)`?

Comment: `ParseErrorException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's no simple and elegant solution for this problem, so I just moved verification into Java code and use it's result in template as boolean variable:

```
#if($isBar)checked#end
```

Comment: Technically, there is a simple and elegant solution: upgrade from version 1.4. It's unfortunate that you can't do that. :(  That said, moving the check into Java is the right call! Simple templates are just as much a good thing as are up-to-date template engines!